# remove vertical space html

Tags: css, html

This should be a simple question, but I haven't been able to find the answer. In creating a single-column html/css design, there is extraneous space vertically between elements that I cannot account for.

The space occurs between sections and can be moved by setting the section top margin to `-20px`, but this approach shouldn't be necessary. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            padding:0;
            background-color: #888888;
            width:800;

            margin-top:0;
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
            margin-bottom:0;
            display:block;
            vertical-align:0;
        }

        section {
            display:block;
            margin-top:0px;
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
            margin-bottom:0;

            padding-top:0;
            padding-left:20px;
            padding-right:20px;
            padding-bottom:20px;

            background-color: #CCCCCC;
            width:760px;
        }

        article {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            background-color: #EEEEEE;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <section>
        <h2> Section 1 </h2>
        <article>
            <p> Text here.
            </p>
        </article>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h2> Section 2 </h2>
        <article>
            <p> Text here.
            </p>
        </article>
    </section>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This margin is from your browsers default css (user agent style) for the `h2` headlines. You can get rid of it by setting the margin to zero.

```
h2 {
     margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I assumed that it couldn't be the h2 because an added margin there would extend the height of the containing element's background, but I was mistaken!

Answer (score 1):

The extra margin is from your `<h2>`

Answer (score -1):

you could use normalize css to get rid of this issues 
https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/
This normalize.css will normalize all the browser default stylesheet